# MyBatis mapper with DTO

Tags: java, mybatis, mapper

Is it posible to use DTO objects in MyBatis mapper?
For example, replace following never-ending signature of method findPolicy

```
@Mapper
public interface PolicyMapper {
    List<Policy> findPolicy(
            @Param("partnerId") Long partnerId,
            @Param("policyNo") Long policyNo,
            @Param("policyStatus") Integer policyStatus,
            @Param("policyOpenDateFrom") Date policyOpenDateFrom,
            @Param("policyOpenDateTo") Date policyOpenDateTo,
            @Param("policyFinalDateFrom") Date policyFinalDateFrom,
            @Param("policyFinalDateTo") Date policyFinalDateTo,
            // ....
```

with simple DTO object?

```
@Mapper
public interface PolicyMapper {
    List<Policy> findPolicy(@ParametersAutoBinding PolicyFilterDto filter);
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course with:

```
List<Policy> findPolicy(PolicyFilterDto filter);
```

you access directly to properties of `PoliceFilterDto`.

Parameters have to be named when there are multiple.

```
List<Policy> findPolicy(@Param("filter") PolicyFilterDto filter, @Param("another") AnotherDto another);
```